# Does a premium / for sale theme need to go through the Wordpress approval process?

Tags: theme-development, premium

I am about to finish 2 themes for sale. Do I need to put these through the Wordpress.org approval process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they don't need. They will need to go through the approval process of the marketplace where you will sell them (if any).